# Error Message: "You must change the sites/all/libraries/mpdf/graph_cache permissions to be writable, as mPDF requires write-access to that directory."

Tags: files

I'm getting the following error message:

"You must change the sites/all/libraries/mpdf/graph_cache permissions to be writable, as mPDF requires write-access to that directory."

The problem is that it is writable by apache and it has the correct permissions.

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hpadmin apache      22 Jul  2 10:51 graph_cache
```

Comment: Did you set the permissions recursivly for the folder an not for something inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the server was using SELinux that was overriding file permissions made using chmod. Hence, even with 777 permissions the file wasn't writable. The solution was to contact the hosting company and get them to change the configuration of SELinux.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it looks like it's not writeable by the "apache" user. It's read only. It is writeable by the "hpadmin" user though. Currently "hpadmin" is the owner and "apache" is the group.

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hpadmin apache      22 Jul  2 10:51 graph_cache
```

vs

```
drwxrwxr-x.  2 hpadmin apache      22 Jul  2 10:51 graph_cache
```

You can adjust the permission to group writeable with

```
chmod 775 sites/all/libraries/mpdf/graph_cache
```

or change "apache" to the owner with

```
chown apache:apache sites/all/libraries/mpdf/graph_cache
```

Comment: Thanks David. I tried changing it to 775 and even 777 but it still gives me that error message even after flushing the cache.

Comment: Check the parent folder permission also

Comment: My directory looks like public_html/sites/all/libraries/mpdf/graph_cache isn't it a security risk if I make the entire public_html directory writable by apache? At the moment it is read only.

Comment: Not the whole tree, just the permissions on the mpdf folder

Comment: David see my answer. It turns out it was SELinux that was overriding file permissions. SO frustrating. Thanks for your help.